# Shelljs - awk not replacing given format

Tags: javascript, awk, shelljs

I've spent the past hours trying to figure out what the issue with the code below is. What I am trying to do is write the content of a request body to a file, and then remove the `\n`s from there with enter (I am saving markdown and I need the double enter to keep the markdown valid).

When running the following in my router:

```
// working code
... 
if (shell.exec(`echo "${blog.content}" > ${blogTitleWithDash}.md`).code !==0) {
    logger.error('Error! writing to file failed!');
    return res.status(500).json('Error! Something went wrong');
}
// replace \n
if (shell.exec(`awk '{gsub(/\\\\n/,\"\\n\\n\")}1' ${blogTitleWithDash}.md > ${blogTitleWithDash}2.md`).code !== 0) {
    logger.error('Error! Awk failed!');
    return res.status(500).json('Error! Something went wrong');
}
```

it seems like nothing is being changed in the file. I've tried replacing other characters, but that didn't work. However, taking the string which is passed to `shell.exec()` and running it from the command line works perfectly:
`awk '{gsub(/\\n/,"\n\n")}1' This-is-a-test-blog.md > This-is-a-test-blog2.md`

Am I misusing `shelljs` or did I mess up the `awk` command?

Comment: Just a tip.  Replaced old and deprecated backtics with parentheses if you code accept it.  Ex `$(awk '{gsub(/\\\\n/,\"\\n\\n\")}1' ${blogTitleWithDash}.md > ${blogTitleWithDash}2.md)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Jotne, but that didn't work with `shelljs`. However, your suggestion got me thinking about `sed` and I fixed my issue using:
```shell.sed('-i', /\\n/g, '\n\n', `${blogTitleWithDash}.md`)```